# Sharing data between OpenID's the Google Docs way?

Tags: openid

What is the best way to share data between different openid's based on email account. E.g.

1. User1 log in to mysite with OpenID
2. Create some data
3. Hit 'Share with' and put in email adresse of User2
4. User2 log into mysite with OpenID (related to the email User1 provided)
5. User2 access data created by User1

Can this be done reliable?

Comment: Can you elaborate on step 4 a little more?

Comment: Yes, User2 log into mysite with his OpenID. Mysite ask for his email (in my case GetExtension in DotNetOpenAuth). If the email address returned from the openid, match the email address User1 shared with, then mysite know that User2 can access the data provide by user1 (the data is of course store on mysite)

It should be safe, but I have to be sure that the openid will return an email address when asked (eg x@gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a a bad idea to depend on the email address provided by openid, because an use can input provide anything as an email and it isn't verified in any way (so you'd need to do that yourself).

Other than that, the question isn't related to openid at all, since it doesn't store any data.
Store it in a database, or something -- it's no different than storing user's data without openid.